# WordPress navigation wont appear with wp_head

Tags: php, theme-development, navigation, twitter-bootstrap

so im building a custom theme and ive got stuck on the navigation

if i use wp_head(); it loads bootstrap and my custom style sheet but not the navigation
if i use get_header(); it loads the navigation but not bootstrap or my custom style sheet

here is my functions.php

```
function register_navwalker(){
    require_once get_template_directory() . '/inc/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php';
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_navwalker' );

function wpbootstrap_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpbootstrap_enqueue_styles');

register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'main_menu'=>'Main Menu',
    )
);
```

here is my navigation code in header.php

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-controls="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Toggle navigation', 'your-theme-slug' ); ?>">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location'    => 'main_menu',
                'depth'             => 2,
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
            ) );
            ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: there's no `wp_header` function in WordPress, are you sure you're calling `wp_head()` in your `header.php`? There are a handful of things that are not optional that all PHP themes must do, such as `wp_head` in the header, `wp_footer` in the footer, etc, you should check the theme handbook to confirm you're doing these things

Comment: sorry that was a typo i meant wp_head();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call ***both*** `wp_head` and `get_header`.

In your `header.php`, place a call to `wp_head();` inside the `<head>` tag, then use `get_header()` inside your templates.

Comment: thankyou for your help worked a treat

Comment: so its showing up in inspect element that the style sheets and scripts are linked to the page but its not actually using any bootstrap styling from the classes any advice for this

Comment: none, I'm not a bootstrap user, if you've confirmed that the bootstrap CSS is loading but none of the styles are being applied to your HTML then you need bootstrap help not WP help

Comment: ok mate thank you for your help